# Schedule task to run once per week in java

Tags: java, events, schedule

What would be the best way to schedule an event to run every Monday at 00:00?

Note though the app is running 24/7. So OS based schedulers such as cron are not needed.

Comment: can you give some info about your environment?

Comment: Depends on platform. Windows?

Comment: My favorite is http://quartz-scheduler.org/ , but depending on your framework/development environment (AppEngine or stuff like that), other options may arise.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could embed a [Quartz Scheduler](http://quartz-scheduler.org/) in your Java app if it's a long running app. Quartz is a very flexible/powerful scheduler that can be configured in many ways.

Alternatively, if you simply want to run a Java process at a particular time then you should look at [cron](http://www.unixgeeks.org/security/newbie/unix/cron-1.html).

Edit: Given that your app is 24/7 (noting comments above), Quartz is definitely the way forward.

Comment: Thank you, am taking a look at Quartz now!

Comment: Many thanks, works well! Very very easy to implement too.     cronSchedule("0 0 0 ? * MON")

Answer (score 1):

I think [cron4J](http://www.sauronsoftware.it/projects/cron4j/) may be your best bet. You can then configure it to run at ceratin times.

Answer (score 1):

Us the OS scheduler; either cron, Windows task scheduler or similar